# Using Sed to replace old timestamp with current one

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'd like to use Sed to find within a template.php file the unix timestamp portion of the name of a JS file and replace it with a current timestamp. The old timestamp will vary so I need a regex to match a number.

Here's what I have so far:

```
TimPeterson$ current_timestamp=date +%s
TimPeterson$ sed -i "" "s/myJS-[0-9]*\([0-9]\+\).js/myJS-$current_timestamp.js/" template.php
```

Just to be clear on the problem, what I need to match in the JS file name looks something like this (where the number part is variable):

```
myJS-1361297970.js
```

However, `[0-9]*\([0-9]\+\)` isn't correct.

Answer (score 3):

The code as it stands does not work for several reasons. Compare it with:

```
current_timestamp=`date +%s`
sed -ie "s/myJS-[0-9]\+\.js/myJS-${current_timestamp}.js/g" template.php
```

Comments:

1. `date +%s` has to be inside backquotes to get the output of the execution of the program into the `current_timestamp` variable
2. The pattern `[0-9]\+` is enough to capture all the names with a series of digits.
3. I added braces to delimit variable name
4. Protected the dot of the `.js` part not to be confused with the metacharacter `.`, that matches any character but carriage return.
5. I added a "g" modifier to the substitution to produce several substitution in the same line.

Comment: sorry to bug you but there has to be something else going on b/c your code isn't working for me. I just copy pasted everything so really confused. Your code replaces `myJS-1361297970.js` with the current timestamp, i.e., `myJS-1361318815.js` (notice the difference).

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what it is the problem. In your question you say you want the old timestamp part of the file name to be replaced by the new timestamp. This is what this code does.

Comment: can you provide a full working script that includes the hypothetical file contents that need to be replaced?

Comment: Mmm... Maybe you need the "`-e`" option, that was missing in your example, and specifies the pattern to apply. Please, try with this modifications.

Comment: Hmm, yeah that didn't work either. My impression is that ["-e" is for multiple commands anyway](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-13).

Comment: Please, be more specific "that didn't work" does not give enough information. What are the expected results? What results are you obtaining now?

Comment: "Didn't work" means its still not doing the replacement. Meaning the instance of `myJS-1361297970.js` in my template.php file **isn't** getting changed to `myJS-1361318815.js`. It's still just `myJS-1361297970.js`.

Comment: if i get rid of the number part, `myJS-.js`, then the replacement works so the problem is somewhere in here: `myJS-[0-9]\+\.js`

Comment: OK, please, try again, because it seems the `-i` parameter has to have the prefix attached, and not as another argument. Now I tested it with an example and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

- you need `$(..)` to execute the command. `current_timestamp=$(date +%s)`
- you don't have to group , just simply `myJs-[0-9]\+\.js` is enough.
- if your sed supports `-r`, it could save some escaping.

Answer (score 2):

One way using `perl`. I evaluate the substitution part to get the result of `date +%s` from the shell. Last `tr` command removes an additional newline added by the `qx<...>` command.

```
perl -i.bak -lpe 's/(myJS-)\d+(\.js)/$1 . qx<date +%s> . $2/eg && tr/\n//d' infile
```

Comment: -@Birei thanks this worked. The only problem is i'd like to save the `date +%s` as a variable since I need that exact same timestamp elsewhere in my script. I don't know perl at all, would you mind sharing how that would look?