# sed replacing numbers in string

Tags: linux, macos, bash, sed

I can replace text in a string but as soon as I try and put in numbers it fails to match.

**NOTE** that this `[0-9]\+\` is causing the problem.

This works:

```
sed -i "" -e "s/mySite-.js/mySite$current_timestamp.js/" template.php
```

This doesn't:

```
sed -i "" -e "s/mySite-[0-9]\+\.js/mySite$current_timestamp.js/" template.php
```

I apologize for asking [this question earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967483/using-sed-to-replace-old-timestamp-with-current-one) but I've spent almost a full day on this stupid thing and I'm going crazy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please consider including sample data, and expected output.

If you're looking to remove repeating numbers with your `[0-9]\+`, try removing the `\` and just use `[0-9]+`.

If that doesn't work then your sed doesn't support `+`, so use

```
 sed -i "" -e "s/mySite-[0-9][0-9]*\.js/mySite$current_timestamp.js/"  template.php
```

IHTH

Comment: @shelter, that's it! it looks like my version of sed doesn't support `+`, thanks! life can go on!

Comment: @timpeterson You could also try matching `[0-9]+` with sed using the option `-r` which enables extended regexps (at least in some versions of sed, e.g. GNU sed 4.2.1).

Comment: I tried `-r` earlier that didn't work, i'm just using a MacOSX 10.7.6 so not sure how that this is an edge case.